# Sort commits topologically using jgit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm having a issue where commits are being displayed out of order. The reason is not important, I just need to retrieve the commits and display them correctly in a changelog. 
I have done some research and the best solution I can find is using jGits RevSort.TOPO to sort a RevWalk topologically using jGit.
This is what i have so far but it does not work, commits are being returned as before unsorted. Other sorting methods are working fine e.g. RevSort.REVERSE but TOPO is not having any effect

```
    RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo);
    ObjectId head = repo.resolve("HEAD");
    RevCommit recentCommit = walk.parseCommit(head);
    walk.sort(RevSort.TOPO);
    walk.sort(RevSort.COMMIT_TIME_DESC, true);
    walk.markStart(mostRecentCommit);

    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Iterator<RevCommit> iterator = walk.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        RevCommit commit = iterator.next();
        messages.add(commit.getFullMessage());
    }
```

Using git log it gives the below. Commit a867b4a - Added new functionality should be in the next version 1.12.

```
$ git log
commit a867b4af366350be2e7c21b8de9cc6504678a61b`
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 4 18:59:41 2010 -0400
      - prepare release version 1.12

commit 25eee4caef46ae64aa08e8ab3f988bc917ee1ce4
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 4 05:13:39 2010 -0400
      - More stuff

commit 0766c053c0ea2035e90f504928f8df3c9363b8bd
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 4 00:55:06 2010 -0400
         prepare release version **1.11**

commit **a867b4af366350be2e7c21b8de9cc6504678a61b`**
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 4 18:59:41 2010 -0400
      - Added new functionality
```

git log --topo-order works Commit a867b4a - Added new functionality is in the correct tag 1.12

```
$ git log --topo-order
commit a867b4af366350be2e7c21b8de9cc6504678a61b`
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 4 18:59:41 2010 -0400
      - prepare release version 1.12

commit 25eee4caef46ae64aa08e8ab3f988bc917ee1ce4
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 4 05:13:39 2010 -0400
      - More stuff

commit **a867b4af366350be2e7c21b8de9cc6504678a61b`**
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 4 18:59:41 2010 -0400
      - Added new functionality

commit 0766c053c0ea2035e90f504928f8df3c9363b8bd
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 4 00:55:06 2010 -0400
         prepare release version 1.11
```